# need code for timer dispay when call got connected during Calling in android

Tags: android

hi to all respected android devlopers..
could anybody please help me out form this android calling scenario?.my question to you is
How do i get the code for the time spent in call when call connected in android?

thanks in advance

Jayesh

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) class in android